# QueryBuilder and entity with ManyToMany relation

Tags: symfony, doctrine, query-builder

In the database, I have a table User (idUser, name...) and a table Role(IdRole, description..).
Between the two of them there is a link table HasRole (idUser, idRole).

Generating the entity with the Symfony command line, the HasRole entity is not generated. Instead, in the User Entity I have this on the role property :

```
* @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="MyBundle\Entity\Role", inversedBy="utilisateur")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="hasrole",
 *   joinColumns={
 *     @ORM\JoinColumn(name="UTILISATEUR", referencedColumnName="ID")
 *   },
 *   inverseJoinColumns={
 *     @ORM\JoinColumn(name="ROLE", referencedColumnName="ID")
 *   }
 * )
```

I would like to create in the UserRepository a method that returns all of the users for one id Role.

It should starts like this :

```
$qb = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder()
        ->select('utilisateur')
        ->from('ACCUEILBundle:User', 'utilisateur');
```

can u help ?

Ty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use Doctrine to generate your ManyToMany join table, then indeed you will not have an entity for that.

If you **need** to have the join table as an entity (for example because you store additional data in that table), then you should create relationship in the following way:

```
entityA <-OneToMany-> joinEntity <-ManyToOne-> entityB
```

However in your case, it should suffice to just get the Role with the desired ID and then get the users from that:

```
$role = $entityManager->getRepository('Role')->find($id);
$users = $role->getUsers(); //(or getUtilisatuers(), if I see correctly)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm giving you an example so that you can work on it to adopt it into your case. I've removed most of entity properties/annotation to keep it simple for you to get the picture.

In example below, there is Student (M) to (N) Subject relationship. To achieve M-N, you can Student (1) to (N) StudentSubject (N) to (1) Subject so the relationships are held in StudentSubject entity.

**Student**

```
class Student
{
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="StudentSubject", mappedBy="studentMap", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
     */
    protected $studentInverse;
}
```

**Subject**

```
class Subject
{
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="StudentSubject", mappedBy="subjectMap", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
     */
    protected $subjectInverse;
}
```

**StudentSubject**

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="School\FrontendBundle\Repository\StudentSubjectRepository")
 */
class StudentSubject
{
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Student", inversedBy="studentInverse")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="student", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false, onDelete="CASCADE")
     */
    protected $studentMap;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Subject", inversedBy="subjectInverse")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="subject", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false, onDelete="CASCADE")
     */
    protected $subjectMap;
}
```

**Example Query:**

This query select only given fields from Student and Subject entities.

```
class StudentSubjectRepository extends EntityRepository
{
    public function findAll()
    {
        $fields = [
            'st.id AS stId',
            'st.studentId AS stStId',
            'sb.id AS sbId',
            'sb.code AS sbCode',
        ];

        return
            $this
                ->createQueryBuilder('ss')
                ->select($fields)
                ->join('ss.studentMap', 'st')
                ->join('ss.subjectMap', 'sb')
                ->addOrderBy('st.studentId', 'ASC')
                ->addOrderBy('sb.code', 'ASC')
                ->getQuery()
                ->getResult(Query::HYDRATE_SCALAR);
    }
}
```